# SQL join on two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I join two tables on either value?

```
select cases.*
from client_cases
inner join cases on client_cases.id = cases.timeline
left join customers on client_cases.customer_id = customers.id or customers.email = 'test@gmail.com'
where cases.timeline in (
    select timeline from cases where cases.payload -> 'person' ->> 'phone' ~ '4625152'
)
```

I'm trying to get a result if either customers.email = 'test@gmail.com' or if the cases.payload JSONB phone field has the value '4625152'

The above query will only return a result if the phone number has a match. Not if the email has a match and the phone number doesn't.

Comment: Shouldn't `customers.email = 'test@gmail.com'` be in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I'm afraid that just reverses the problem, then I get a result only if the email has a match, but not the phone number.

Comment: It will get all of them.  It's an OR condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to put email condition in WHERE clause.

```
select cases.*
from client_cases
inner join cases on client_cases.id = cases.timeline
left join customers on client_cases.customer_id = customers.id 
where cases.timeline in (
    select timeline from cases where cases.payload -> 'person' ->> 'phone' ~ '4625152'
) or customers.email = 'test@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `on` clause is used when the `join` is looking for matching rows. 
The `where` clause is used to filter rows after all the joining is done.

you have been doing the join with `customers.email = 'test@gmail.com'` but you filter that with `WHERE case.timeline IN..`.. That's explain the result you had

```
SELECT cases.*
FROM client_cases
INNER JOIN cases ON (client_cases.id = cases.timeline)
LEFT JOIN customers ON (client_cases.customer_id = customers.id)
WHERE cases.timeline IN (
    SELECT timeline 
    FROM cases 
    WHERE cases.payload -> 'person' ->> 'phone' ~ '4625152'
) OR customers.email = 'test@gmail.com'
```